# Converting objective-c code to java gives compile error

Tags: java, android, ios, opencv, objective-c++

Here is part of compilable code writen in objective c++

```
cv::Mat blurred(image);
medianBlur(image, blurred, 9);

cv::Mat gray0(blurred.size(), CV_8U), gray;
cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
{
    int ch[] = {c, 0};
    mixChannels(&blurred, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

    const int threshold_level = 2;
    for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++)
    {
        if (l == 0)
        {
            Canny(gray0, gray, 50, 150, 3); 
            dilate(gray, gray, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1));
        }
        else
        {
            gray = gray0 >= (l+1) * 255 / threshold_level;
```

//here is compile problem in AppCode but code compiles ok and works...
            }
     ....

This is how I wrote it in java but I stopped on final line that I don't understand and cant write in java to be compiled correctly, Even in AppCode editor as obecectiv-c code it is highlighted as error but compiles without problem. So I think AppCode parser has problem to understand it also but anyway code works and I have seen other problems with AppCode parser so I don't care , I use static imports, but what i need to understand is just that final line, code continues further and is quite complex...

```
    Mat blurred = new Mat();
    Imgproc.medianBlur(image, blurred, 9);  
    Mat gray0 = new Mat(blurred.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Vector<Vector<Point>> contours = new Vector<>();

    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        Core.mixChannels(list(blurred), list(gray0), new MatOfInt(ch));
        int threshold_level = 2;
        for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++) {
            if (l == 0) {
                Canny(gray0, gray, 50, 150, 3, false);
                dilate(gray, gray, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 1);
            } else {
                gray = gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / threshold_level;  //here is compile problem and I don't understand line at all...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / threshold_level` resolves to a boolean value, and gray is defined as a (presumably) numeric type. Objective-C handles booleans differently than Java. Try redefining gray to be a boolean.

Comment: Mat gray0 ,Mat gray if you see both are objects... Mat , in objective C++ this compiles somehow...

Comment: Sorry that was java but here is it in objective c++ cv::Mat gray0(blurred.size(), CV_8U), gray; Mat is complex type , just look at opncv library its well known open source multi-platform library... Mat is not numeric  type for sure... Maybe there is some magic in c++ I don't know that converts between numeric and types ? I don't know really , thats why I posted question... probably for c++ expert...

Comment: Does cv::Mat have an operator overload for the >= operator?

Comment: This can be it... I am looking into it.. Thank's.  Answer question if you wan I will accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested, above, it looks like cv::Mat has some overloaded operators that are hiding some functionality. [This doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator) indicates that at least some operators are overloaded.

And this is final solution in java of that magic line:

```
 Core.compare(gray0, new Mat(gray0.size(), gray0.type(), new Scalar((l + 1) * 255 / threshold_level)), gray, Core.CMP_GE);
```